# Need to know if I should switch class to batch or queueable or do something totally different

Tags: apex, future

I have a method using `@future`, that seems to have "outgrown" that. Its a method that is kicked off by process builder after a nightly external job comes in a updates a bunch of SF records. It basically queries for a bunch of opportunities, then for a bunch of customer object records (which was just updated from the external service), compares them, and makes updates to the opps. It is now failing with this message a lot:

> First error: Update failed. First exception on row 200 with id xxxxxxxxxxxxx; first error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, We can't save this record because the “Opportunity” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details

I believe two things are at play. First, we have more and more opps that meet the criteria, as well as the custom object records. And we have more automation around the opp object which I believe is causing this to timeout. That is a opp process builder in the error message.

So my question is, for a job like this, should I switch the future method to batch or queueable or something else. FYI, it doesn't matter how long it takes to run so long its within an hour or so. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should definitely check for any new validation rules - including any that are on other records (child or parents) modified as part of the flow. When you save using allOrNone, the true source error can be difficult to track.

Answer (score 2):

Realistically, it probably doesn't matter. You can use Queueable and Finalizer, or Batchable, with virtually identical end results. If you know you're going to always have lots of records to process, you're probably better off with Batchable, as it makes it easier to query the data you need. If you just need "a bit more" governor limits, then you might go with Queueable. Given that data volumes tend to go up over time, I'd suggest Batchable would serve long-term goals better.

Comment: I would say that an advantage of queueable is the opportunity to use a transaction finalizer that can allow your code to recover from errors, including governor limit violations. Batchables are potentially slightly less efficient in number of async executions used, but they also have a guaranteed continuation of execution even if a given call to `execute` fails with a limit violation. Very much swings and roundabouts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses everyone. Actually, switching it to a batch apex class seems to have resolved the issues.

Comment: SFSE is a Qs & As site, not a threaded forum. Your "answer" here is more appropriate as a comment under *sfdcfox*'s answer - especially since going with a batch class was his recommendation. You normally need 50 rep to comment under someone else's post; however, since you wrote the original question, you should be able to comment under his answer. So I recommend that you 1) accept his answer (that helps future readers of this question, and it helps clean things up so that the "Bot" doesn't think this question is unanswered), 2) put this as a comment under his answer, and 3) delete this answer.